# toggle a bit at ith positon

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c)

Can some one help me how to toggle a bit at ith position.
One way is to do `((n>>i) ^ 1) << i`. Are there any other ways ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n ^= 1U << i` is easy enough, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

You could do

```
pow(2, i) ^ n
```

Comment: you'd have to cast the (inexact) result of pow to an int for that to work.

Comment: No, you couldn't.  `pow` returns a double, which is not a valid argument to the `^` operator.  There's also no guarantee that `pow` will give an exact result.