# Toggle a Specific Bit

Tags: c, assembly, x86, bit-manipulation

So I have seen the questions like
[toggle a bit at ith positon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681684/toggle-a-bit-at-ith-positon) and [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit), but I was wondering if there was a good way to toggle a bit in the ith position in x86-64 assembly?

I tried writing it in C and looking through the assembly and don't quite understand exactly why there are some things that are there.

C:

```
unsigned long toggle(unsigned long num, unsigned long bit)
{
  num ^= 1 << bit;
  return num;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%ld\n", toggle(100, 60));
  return 0;
}
```

Toggle function assembly from GDB:

```
<toggle>
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
mov QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rdi
mov QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
mov edx, 0x1
mov ecx, eax
shl edx, cl
mov eax, edx
cdqe
xor QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
pop rbp
ret
```

Can someone walk me through what's going on on the assembly level so I can better understand this and write my own toggle function in x86-64?

Comment: Looking at some obscure compiler output of a function is not a best way to learn how to actually write this function. If you know assembly you can come up with a proper implementation yourself. Or even google it.

Comment: BTW your code has undefined behaviour. `1 << bit` results in *signed* int being set. If `bit` >= 31 behaviour is undefined; and in the resulting assembly code, bits > = 32 cannot be set at all.

Comment: The proper code is **`1UL`** `<< bit` and the generated assembly would be more sensible.

Comment: you also have undefined behavior in `printf("%ld\n", toggle(100, 60));` when the function returns `unsigned long` which must be printed using `%lu`

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback, everyone!

Comment: You compiled without optimization, which introduces a significantly amount of trash instructions.

Comment: With optimizations on, `num ^= (num*0 + 1) << bit;`  insures the mask is the right width/type.

Comment: To toggle a bit on x86, use the `btc` instruction.

Comment: @chux: Would this do for `short int num`?

Comment: @alk With `short int num`, `num ^= (num*0 + 1) << bit;` and `num ^= 1 << bit;` would result in the function.  `num ^= an_int_with_the_value_of_1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was a good way to toggle a bit in the ith position in x86-64 assembly?

Yes, [x86's `BTC` (Bit Test and Complement) instruction does exactly that](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BTC.html) (as well as setting CF to the old value of the bit), and runs efficiently on all modern CPUs.

- Intel SnB-family: 1 uop, 1c latency, 2 per clock throughput.  (Nehalem and earlier: 1 per clock)
- Silvermont/KNL: 1 uop, 1c latency, 1 per clock throughput.
- AMD Ryzen: 2 uops, 2c latency, 2 per clock throughput
- AMD Bulldozer-family / Jaguar: 2 uops, 2c latency, 1 per clock throughput
- AMD K8/K10: 2 uops, 2c latency, 1 per clock throughput

Source: [Agner Fog's instruction tables and x86 optimization guide](http://agner.org/optimize/).  See also other performance links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

```
toggle:
    mov  rax, rdi
    btc  rax, rsi
    ret
```

(If you'd written `toggle` correctly in C).

Don't use `btc` with a memory operand: the bit-string instructions have insane CISC semantics where the bit-index isn't limited to within the dword selected by the addressing mode.  (So `btc m,r` is 10 uops with one per 5c throughput on Skylake).  But with a register operand, the shift-count is masked exactly like variable-count shifts.

Unfortunately gcc and clang miss this peephole optimization, even with `-march=haswell` or `-mtune=intel`.  It's worth using even on AMD, but it's even more efficient on Intel.

---

#### Repeated use of the same `1ULL << bit` with multiple inputs

On AMD CPUs where `btc` is slower than `xor`, it's worth generating the mask in a register and using `xor`.  Or even on Intel CPUs, this is worth it to toggle a bit in memory.  (memory-destination `xor` is much better than memory-destination `btc`).

For multiple elements in an array, use SSE2 `pxor`.  You can generate the mask with:

```
pcmpeqd  xmm0, xmm0        ; -1 all bits set
psrlq    xmm0, 63          ;  1 just a single bit set

movd     xmm1, esi
psllq    xmm0, xmm1        ; 1<<bit


; then inside a loop, with data in xmm1
pxor     xmm1, xmm0        ; flip bit in each qword element
```

---

> don't quite understand exactly why there are some things that are there.

All that crap is there because you compiled without optimization, and because you used a signed `int` constant.

---

It's not even worth looking at all the spill/reload to memory from the `-O0` code.  Compile with `-O3 -march=native` if you want code that doesn't suck.

See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output), and **Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk: [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)** for a good intro to looking at compiler-generated asm.

---

Using the signed `int` constant `1 << bit` explains why gcc did a 32-bit shift and then `cdqe`.  `num ^= 1 << bit;` is equivalent to

```
int mask = 1;
mask <<= bit;   // still signed int
num ^= mask;    // mask is sign-extended to 64-bit here.
```

In gcc -O3 output, we get

```
    mov     edx, 1
    sal     edx, cl           # 1<<bit   (32-bit)
    movsx   rax, edx          # sign-extend, like cdqe does for eax->rax
    xor     rax, rdi
```

---

If we write `toggle` corectly:

```
uint64_t toggle64(uint64_t num, uint32_t bit) {
  num ^= 1ULL << bit;
  return num;
}
```

**[(source+asm on the Godbolt compiler explorer)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Aunsigned+long+toggle_orig(unsigned+long+num,+unsigned+long+bit)+%7B%0A++num+%5E%3D+1+%3C%3C+bit%3B+//+signed%0A++return+num%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Auint32_t+toggle32(uint32_t+num,+uint32_t+bit)+%7B%0A++num+%5E%3D+1ULL+%3C%3C+bit%3B%0A++return+num%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Auint64_t+toggle64(uint64_t+num,+uint32_t+bit)+%7B%0A++num+%5E%3D+1ULL+%3C%3C+bit%3B%0A++return+num%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.129119394921666,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3+-mtune%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:29.6056185845489,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl19_64,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:/Ox,source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+MSVC+19+2017+RTW+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:32.25986788974475,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dsandybridge',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)',t:'0')),k:31.611012715333594,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg630,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%234)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:31.611012715333594,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**

gcc and clang still miss using `btc`, but it's not horrible.  Interestingly, MSVC does spot the `btc` peephole, but wastes a MOV instruction:

```
toggle64 PROC
    mov      eax, edx
    btc      rcx, rax
    mov      rax, rcx
    ret      0
```

Using `uint64_t` bit avoids the extra MOV.  It's unnecessary because `btc` with a register destination masks the index with `& 63`.  High garbage is not a problem, but MSVC doesn't know this.

gcc and clang emit code like you'd expect, but with gcc wasting a MOV instruction by generating `1ULL <<bit` in `rdx` and having to copy to `rax`.

```
 ; clang output.
    mov     eax, 1
    mov     ecx, esi
    shl     rax, cl
    xor     rax, rdi
    ret
```

Comment: Awesome response. Thank you so much, I really learned something today!

Comment: @MichaelPetch Whoa, looks like I have enough activity here to upvote. I attempted to about 10 minutes ago and it looks like then I was about 5 rep too low.

Comment: The btc part seems wrong. In Fog's manual, "optimizing_assembly.pdf", he recommends using ´test´, ´or´, etc in favour of ´btc´, ´bts´, etc.

Comment: @z0rberg's: Hmm, good point, I was only answering for the case where the bit-position is a runtime-variable, like when the OP's function can't inline or when it's still not a known constant after inlining.  For a constant bit position from 0..30, it would make sense to use `xor` with a 32-bit immediate instead of `btc`.  (Or for 32-bit operand size, 0..31 because sign-extension to the high 32 bits isn't a problem).  On x86-64, you need `btc` to toggle bits 31..63 with a single instruction.  (For multiple values, I already showed using `pxor` with a mask prepared earlier.)